# What is .NET Core equivalent of Encoding.GetEncodings()

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need to dynamically get list of all encodings and I found this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencodings(v=vs.110).aspx , which works great for the older versions of .net, but I am looking and can't find equivalent for .NET Core.

The solution needs to work on mac and linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Encoding.GetEncodings()` exists as [part of .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Core 2.0](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Text.Encoding.GetEncodings()). I don't know of any alternative for .NET Core 1.x.